# Проблема с разрешением экрана.

Tags: ubuntu

Здравствуйте. У меня Ubuntu 10.04 lts на виртуальной машине. Все работает замечательно, но не могу установить разрешение экрана больше 800х600. Как это исправить? Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо поставить vmware tools если стоит продукт от VMware или vbox guest для VirtualBox.

Answer (score 0):

Наверно потому что в гостевой ос разрешение 800х600.